# How can I delete a UNIX Domain Socket file when I exit my application?

Tags: c, sockets, unix-socket

I have a server application that creates a UNIX Domain Socket in a specific path with a name and `bind()`s to it.

I need to delete the socket only when I close/stop the application intentionally, from within the the application code; otherwise it needs to be open. How do I do this?

Thanks!

**Edit:** Consider that I start and run my application from inside a terminal.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You're making this harder than it needs to be. Put the `unlink()` right before the `bind()`. That's how everybody else does it. (Example: [BSD syslogd](http://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/head/usr.sbin/syslogd/syslogd.c?revision=291328&view=markup#l565), one of the classic unix-domain-socket-based services)

Comment: thank you. i thought i had to go after the bind. thanks for specifying it had to go before.

Comment: You could still do an unlink on exit to prevent the stale socket from showing up in directory listings when the server isn't running. But that's purely cosmetic.

Answer (score 6):

If you have multiple exit points from your application and you don't want to modify each of them to call cleanup routine, then you may use "dirty" approach.

When socket is just created, register cleanup routine with `atexit(3)`. Routine (which is simply a call to `unlink(2)`) will be called when application is terminated normally. But it won't be called if application is terminated with signal. So, if you want to cleanup after receiving SIGINT and similar signals, you also need to setup signal handlers properly.

Comment: ok, but the file still remais there. I also need to delete the file from the folder

Comment: @Pheonix7, have you checked exit code of unlink for errors?

Comment: when i exit the application with ctr+c the terminal doesnt say anything. When i restart the application i get a bind error: Address in use

Answer (score 4):

You can check if socket if active by looking at /proc/net/unix. Then delete, ether in a cron, or before you start/restart your application.

```
echo "active sockets in /path/"
cat /proc/net/unix | grep -Eo '/path/.*'

echo "all sockets in path including stale sockets"
ls -1F /path/ | egrep '=$' | sed 's/=$//'

echo "example command to remove stale sockets"
comm -1 -3 <(cat /proc/net/unix | grep -Eo '/path/.*' | sort)  <(ls -1F /path/ | egrep '=$' | sed 's/=$//' | sort) | xargs -n1 echo rm
```

Answer (score 1):

Just execute

```
unlink("Path/to/Socket");
```

before you exit your program.

Comment: but i exit my application from the terminal, so where would i put the unlink in the code?

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the socket file with a simple:

```
unlink(path);
```

Wherever you program exit your program, check if it exists, and remove it.

Comment: but i exit my application from the terminal, so where would i put the unlink in the code?

Comment: It doesn't matter where you exit your application from, unless you're saying that you're hitting `Control-C` or something.  In that case, you need to create a signal handler that takes care of the socket before exiting.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Linux, you can use an abstract namespace socket: Set the first byte in the `sockaddr_un.sun_path` to `\0`, and with bytes still in this array. An abstract socket is not placed on the filesystem, which has mild side effects.

## References

1. https://gavv.net/articles/unix-socket-reuse/
2. `man 7 unix`

> **Abstract sockets**
>
> Socket  permissions have no meaning for abstract sockets: the process umask(2) has no effect when binding an abstract socket, and changing the ownership and permissions of the object (via fchown(2) and fchmod(2))  has no effect on the accessibility of the socket.
>
> Abstract sockets automatically disappear when all open references to the socket are closed.
>
> The abstract socket namespace is a nonportable Linux extension.