# Integration between Node.js and C++

Tags: c++, node.js, ipc, poco-libraries

I have a Node.js application that I want to be able to send a JSON-object into a C++ application.

The C++ application will use the Poco-libraries (pocoproject.org).

I want the interaction to be lighting fast, so preferably no files or network-sockets.
I have been looking into these areas:

- Pipes
- Shared memory
- unixSockets

What should I focus on, and can someone point my direction to docs. and samples?

Comment: I think you're going to need to edit this question to show what you've done.  We can't really do your research for you.  I would suggest making some sample apps using those 3 methods and post to codereview.stackexchange.com to see if you can tweak anything to make them better.

Comment: Shared memeory can be faster especially with large amounts of data because there is less copying of the data. However you also will have todo some form of signalling and synchronization which makes it much harder to get right. What is lightning fast? You should be able to reach more then 10,000 request per second on a unix domain socket for small messages.

Comment: Are you sure that you need any IPC at all? As far as know - node.js have native addons functonality, wich can be used to deal with native code (c, c++,fortran etc)

Comment: It is called nan btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I have gone for, is to use unix domain sockets. The solution will run on a Raspbian-setup and the socket-file is placed in /dev/shm, which is mounted into RAM.

On the C++ side, I use the Poco::Net::TCPServer framework as described elsewhere in this post.

On the Node.js side, I use the node-ipc module (http://riaevangelist.github.io/node-ipc/).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, some more data is needed to give good advice.

In general shared memory is the fastest, since there's no transfer required, but it's also the hardest to keep fine. I'm not sure you'd be able to do that with Node though.

If this program is just running for this one task and closing it might be worth just sending your JSON to the CPP program as a startup param

```
myCPPProgram.exe "JsonDataHere"
```

Comment: The Node.js application is getting data from sensors. I am only able to change the function in the Node.js application that determines what to do when sensor data has arrived. I want this data to be sent to a C++ application that is running 24/7.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing with decent performance should be a socket connection using Unix domain sockets with some low-overhead data frame format. E.g., two-byte length followed by UTF-8 encoded JSON. On the C++ side this should be easy to implement using the `Poco::Net::TCPServer` framework. Depending on where your application will go in the future you may run into limits of this format, but if it's basically just streaming JSON objects it should be fine.

To make it even simpler, you can use a WebSocket, which will take care of the framing for you, at the cost of the overhead for the initial connection setup (HTTP upgrade request). May even be possible to run the WebSocket protocol over a Unix domain socket.

However, the performance difference between a (localhost only) TCP socket and a Unix domain socket may not even be significant, given all the JavaScript/node.js overhead. Also, if performance is really a concern, JSON may not even be the right serialization format to begin with.

Anyway, without more detailed information (size of JSON data, message frequency) it's hard to give a definite recommendation.

Comment: The applications will at first run on Ubuntu and Raspbian. I looked in the Poco-libraries for IPC functionality and found: NamedEvent, Pipes and SharedMemory. I guess NamedEvent is only used for signaling that an event has happened, but I am not sure how to interact with this from Node.js. Pipes are supported in Node.js, but i am not sure about performance. I see Node.js has some C++ addon functionality (NAN), but I am not sure if this can interact with the SharedMemory functionality of the Poco-libraries. Are there any Poco-samples with unix-sockets?

Comment: Don't know Node.js enough to know if there are equivalents to NamedEvent and NamedMutex, in addition to shared memory support. Of course it would be possible to write a native Node.js module that handles the IPC using Poco classes, but the effort would probably not be worth it. Setting up a Poco::Net::TCPServer should be straightforward, just create a Poco::Net::SocketAddress using an absolute path string and pass it to the underlying Poco::Net::ServerSocket. Note that this requires at least Poco release 1.8.0. There's likely no performance difference between pipes and Unix domain sockets.

Comment: What is the right way to deal with the "Net Exception: Address already in use: /tmp/app.SocketTest" error?

Answer (score 0):

I created a TCPServer, which seems to work. However if I close the server and start it again I get this error:

> Net Exception: Address already in use: /tmp/app.SocketTest

Is it not possible to re-attach to the socket if it exists?

Here is the code for the TCPServer:

```
#include "Poco/Util/ServerApplication.h"
#include "Poco/Net/TCPServer.h"
#include "Poco/Net/TCPServerConnection.h"
#include "Poco/Net/TCPServerConnectionFactory.h"
#include "Poco/Util/Option.h"
#include "Poco/Util/OptionSet.h"
#include "Poco/Util/HelpFormatter.h"
#include "Poco/Net/StreamSocket.h"
#include "Poco/Net/ServerSocket.h"
#include "Poco/Net/SocketAddress.h"
#include "Poco/File.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using Poco::Net::ServerSocket;
using Poco::Net::StreamSocket;
using Poco::Net::TCPServer;
using Poco::Net::TCPServerConnection;
using Poco::Net::TCPServerConnectionFactory;
using Poco::Net::SocketAddress;
using Poco::Util::ServerApplication;
using Poco::Util::Option;
using Poco::Util::OptionSet;
using Poco::Util::HelpFormatter;



class UnixSocketServerConnection: public TCPServerConnection
    /// This class handles all client connections.
{
public:
    UnixSocketServerConnection(const StreamSocket& s): 
        TCPServerConnection(s)
    {
    }

    void run()
    {
        try
        {
            /*char buffer[1024];
            int n = 1;
            while (n > 0)
            {
                n = socket().receiveBytes(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
                EchoBack(buffer);
            }*/

            std::string message;
            char buffer[1024];
            int n = 1;
            while (n > 0)
            {
                n = socket().receiveBytes(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
                buffer[n] = '\0';
                message += buffer;
                if(sizeof(buffer) > n && message != "")
                {
                    EchoBack(message);
                    message = "";
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Poco::Exception& exc)
        {
            std::cerr << "Error: " << exc.displayText() << std::endl;
        }
        std::cout << "Disconnected." << std::endl;
    }

private:
    inline void EchoBack(std::string message)
    {
        std::cout << "Message: " << message << std::endl;
        socket().sendBytes(message.data(), message.length());
    }
};

class UnixSocketServerConnectionFactory: public TCPServerConnectionFactory
    /// A factory
{
public:
    UnixSocketServerConnectionFactory()
    {
    }

    TCPServerConnection* createConnection(const StreamSocket& socket)
    {
        std::cout << "Got new connection." << std::endl;
        return new UnixSocketServerConnection(socket);
    }

private:

};

class UnixSocketServer: public Poco::Util::ServerApplication
    /// The main application class.
{
public:
    UnixSocketServer(): _helpRequested(false)
    {
    }

    ~UnixSocketServer()
    {
    }

protected:
    void initialize(Application& self)
    {
        loadConfiguration(); // load default configuration files, if present
        ServerApplication::initialize(self);
    }

    void uninitialize()
    {
        ServerApplication::uninitialize();
    }

    void defineOptions(OptionSet& options)
    {
        ServerApplication::defineOptions(options);

        options.addOption(
            Option("help", "h", "display help information on command line arguments")
                .required(false)
                .repeatable(false));
    }

    void handleOption(const std::string& name, const std::string& value)
    {
        ServerApplication::handleOption(name, value);

        if (name == "help")
            _helpRequested = true;
    }

    void displayHelp()
    {
        HelpFormatter helpFormatter(options());
        helpFormatter.setCommand(commandName());
        helpFormatter.setUsage("OPTIONS");
        helpFormatter.setHeader("A server application to test unix domain sockets.");
        helpFormatter.format(std::cout);
    }

    int main(const std::vector<std::string>& args)
    {
        if (_helpRequested)
        {
            displayHelp();
        }
        else
        {
            // set-up unix domain socket
            Poco::File socketFile("/tmp/app.SocketTest");
            SocketAddress unixSocket(SocketAddress::UNIX_LOCAL, socketFile.path());

            // set-up a server socket
            ServerSocket svs(unixSocket);
            // set-up a TCPServer instance
            TCPServer srv(new UnixSocketServerConnectionFactory, svs);
            // start the TCPServer
            srv.start();
            // wait for CTRL-C or kill
            waitForTerminationRequest();
            // Stop the TCPServer
            srv.stop();
        }
        return Application::EXIT_OK;
    }

private:
    bool _helpRequested;
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    UnixSocketServer app;
    return app.run(argc, argv);
}
```

Comment: Calling `socketFile.remove()` after `srv.stop();` resolves the problem.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34873151/how-can-i-delete-a-unix-domain-socket-file-when-i-exit-my-application